# How to solve FORWARDING_TO_NODE_FAILED issue in selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng, selenium-grid

I am working on selenium grid since couple days. I have created hub and node for android on same machine. Node is getting registered on hub and execution also getting started. But after some time, session getting failed and execution gets stopped. Hardly 2-3 test cases getting executed.

Please check below error log for your reference

```
[testng] [WebDriverCommandLogger] - Executing findElements parameters: {"using":"css selector","value":".spinner-backdrop"}
   [testng] [WebDriverCommandLogger] - command: findElements[ param-1: {value=.spinner-backdrop, using=css selector}] Result: [id: 0.5843276489161311-137]
   [testng] [WebDriverCommandLogger] - Executing findElements parameters: {"using":"css selector","value":".spinner-backdrop"}
   [testng] [WebDriverCommandLogger] - command: findElements[ param-1: {value=.spinner-backdrop, using=css selector}] Result: []
   [testng] [WebDriverCommandLogger] - Executing findElements parameters: {"using":"css selector","value":".centered-middle"}
   [testng] [WebDriverCommandLogger] - command: findElements[ param-1: {value=.centered-middle, using=css selector}] Result: []
   [testng] [WebDriverCommandLogger] - Executing actions parameters: {"actions":[{}]}
   [testng] [WebDriverCommandLogger] - command: actions[ param-1: {actions=[org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Sequence@7f6f288]}] Result: actions
   [testng] Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
   [testng] System info: host: 'hostname', ip: 'ipaddress', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
   [testng] Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
   [testng] [WebDriverCommandLogger] - Executing screenshot parameters: {}
   [testng] [WebDriverCommandLogger] - command: screenshot[ param-1: {}] Result: Session [c9e02a30-4c4d-4181-a588-7072b4372a90] was terminated due to FORWARDING_TO_NODE_FAILED
   [testng] Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
   [testng] [WebDriverCommandLogger] - Executing screenshot parameters: {}
   [testng] [WebDriverCommandLogger] - command: screenshot[ param-1: {}] Result: Session [c9e02a30-4c4d-4181-a588-7072b4372a90] was terminated due to FORWARDING_TO_NODE_FAILED
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ and your _code trials_

Comment: You need to increase session time

Answer (score 0):

pass the params -e ZALENIUM_EXTRA_JVM_PARAMS="-Dwebdriver.http.factory=apache", like shown below :

docker run --rm -t --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -e ZALENIUM_EXTRA_JVM_PARAMS="-Dwebdriver.http.factory=apache" -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...

It has solved, and discussed here as well : 
https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/issues/593